# A space of ideals

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

**Definition:** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1.  Endow the power set $2^R$ with the product topology.  The *ideal space* $\mathcal{I}(R)$ is defined to be subset of $2^R$ consisting of ideals, equipped with the induced topology.

This is the ring-theoretic analogue of the Gromov--Grigorchuk space of marked groups, which can be used to give nice proofs of simple facts about algebraic geometry over groups (cf. [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401042) by Champetier and Guirardel).  My question is:

> Is the 'ideal space' of a ring a standard construction in commutative algebra or algebraic geometry?  If so, what's it called and where can I read more about it?

My motivation is to strengthen the analogy between algebraic geometry over groups and classical algebraic geometry.

To demonstrate that it's a useful concept, I'll give an application.  But first, here are a few basic facts.

- $\mathcal{I}(R)$ is compact (because it is a closed subset of $2^R$, which is itself compact by Tychonoff's Theorem), Hausdorff and totally disconnected.
- Each point $I\in \mathcal{I}(R)$ is contained in a canonical closed subset

  $U_I=\{J\in \mathcal{I}(R)\mid I\subseteq J \}$

  (which is in fact isomorphic to $\mathcal{I}(R/I)$).
- If $R$ is Noetherian then each $U_I$ is equal to the set of ideals that contain a (finite) generating set for $I$, and hence is open.
- The subset of prime ideals in $\mathcal{I}(R)$ is closed: indeed, for each pair of non-units $x,y$, the subset $N(x,y)=\{x\notin I, y\notin I, xy\in I\}$ is open, and the union of these sets is the complement of the set of prime ideals.

Now here's a sample application -  a proof of a well known lemma.

**Lemma:** If $R$ is a Noetherian ring then there is a finite set of prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{p}_k\subseteq R$ with the property that every prime ideal contains one of the $\mathfrak{p}_i$.

*Proof:* The set of $U_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for $\mathfrak{p}$ prime is an open cover of the set of prime ideals.  Since the set of prime ideals is compact, there is a finite subcover. *QED*

By the way, my research concerns, among other things, algebraic geometry over groups, but it's a few years since I studied algebraic geometry or commutative algebra.  This question has been [reposted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92268/a-space-of-ideals) on MathOverflow.

Comment: Nice question. But does this topology restrict to the Zariski topology on $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$? I only see this right now for noetherian $R$. Another question: What is AG over groups?

Comment: As the topology is Hausdorff and totally disconnected, I don't think it's got much to do with the Zariski topology, has it?

Comment: Algebraic geometry over groups is the fancy name for the study of the 'variety' $\mathrm{Hom}(G,\Gamma)$, where $G$ and $\Gamma$ are groups.  If $G$ has presentation $\langle x_1,\ldots, x_m\mid r_1,\ldots,r_n\rangle$ then this set corresponds exactly to the set of solutions in $\Gamma$ to the equations $\{r_j=1\}$ in the variables $x_i$---hence the name.

Comment: Dear HJRW, I have never heard of the ideal space of a ring but the Lemma you give as an application is a  well-known and easy fact of  beginning commutative algebra. It is proved, for example,  in Miles Reid's *Undergraduate* Commutative Algebra.

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg, of course I realise that the lemma is well known. My question is whether this is a standard or known approach.

Comment: Concerning the lemma: A shorter formulation is that a Noetherian comm. ring has only finitely many minimal primes. And this should be well-known.

Answer (score 2):

This space is considered in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.4216) paper. For a f.g. commutative ring $R$, it determines the topological type of $\mathcal{I}(R)$.

This paper focuses on the case of a finitely generated free commutative ring, but the general case is addressed, see Section 4: it considers, more generally, the case of submodules of an $R$-module ($R$ any ring). The space of ideals of a ring is the particular case of the free module of rank 1.